# How to keep pressed a button untill another button is pressed in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was trying to search about how to keep pressed a button until another button is pressed, I have an `activebackground` color, when I press my button that color is activated only until I stop pressing it, what I want is to keep it pressed untill I press another button. Any advise let me know, thanks.

```
btn_main1 = Button(top, text='FRAME1', bg='gray', bd=3, fg='black',
                          activebackground='goldenrod', font='arial 12 bold', relief='solid',
                          command=lambda: [frame1()])
btn_main0.place(x=10, y=230, width='196', height='50')

btn_main2 = Button(top, text='FRAME2', bg='gray', bd=3, fg='black',
                          activebackground='goldenrod', font='arial 12 bold', relief='solid', 
                          command=lambda :[frame2()])
btn_main.place(x=10, y=410, width='196', height='50')
```

Comment: Do you want to fake the button press or keep pressing it? Maybe if you say what you are trying to mimic, we could give a better solution that this method.

Comment: @CoolCloud Hello mate!, I want to fake the button press, actually each button is opening a frame, so I just want my button's activebackground color keeps pressed untill I push another button.

Comment: Maybe include the code of what your doing currenly.

Comment: @CoolCloud I've edited and included 2 of my buttons

Comment: You can try `tkinter.Radiobutton(options...)` widget and *set indicator option to 0*  (`indicator=0`) [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpTgi.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've thought a way to fake the pressed button. It's working well now. Thanks guys!

```
def active0():
    btn_main0.config(bg='goldenrod')

def disable0():
    btn_main0.config(bg='gray')

def active1():
    btn_main1.config(bg='goldenrod')

def disable1():
    btn_main1.config(bg='gray')


btn_main0 = Button(top, text='FRAME1', bg='gray', bd=3, fg='black',
                          activebackground='goldenrod', font='arial 12 bold', relief='solid',
                          command=lambda: [frame1(), active0(), disable1()])
btn_main0.place(x=10, y=230, width='196', height='50')

btn_main1 = Button(top, text='FRAME2', bg='gray', bd=3, fg='black',
                          activebackground='goldenrod', font='arial 12 bold', relief='solid', 
                          command=lambda :[frame2(), active1(), disable0()])
btn_main1.place(x=10, y=410, width='196', height='50')
```

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the answer, and thank for the followup!